# Can I write a boot loader for atmel MCU using Arduino IDE?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, boot, bootloader, atmel

I am using my bluetooth module HC -05 to communicate through the UART1 of my microcontroller Atmega1284P. I have the memory mapped for both the boot loader and the application section. Now I am wanting to write a boot loader so that it receives hex files via bluetooth when received interrupt. How can I use Arduino IDE in writing a bootloader.? If possible, what are the functions to call the registers of MCU ? What are the function to write a page/erase a page in the specified memory ?
If it is not possible in arduino, what are the alternatives ?

Thanks in advance
Srinivasa Varadhan.

Answer (score 1):

To break your question down into points: yes you can use Arduino IDE to program the bootloader, however it's not advised.  For something like this you will need Atmel Studio since it has the registers built in for your micro to make things a LOT easier.  Personally, I prefer CodeVision AVR to do it, there's a setting for bootloaders and lets you specify your micro.

Second off, if you pull up the datasheet for your micro (ATMega1284P) and look at section 26.8.13, you will see a perfectly good example of writing a page to memory.  There is a whole section on writing the bootloader for that micro on the datasheet, so I would start there.

Also one last thing, yes bootloading sw over bluetooth is possible, but you'll want to make sure you're using proper flow control and checking the checksum of each line (again in the bootloader section).  Also make sure that your bootloader memory area corresponds to that of what the micro is expecting.  You can't really put the bootloader wherever you want and expect it to work.

Answer (score 0):

`I have the memory mapped for both the boot loader and the application section` -- what does this mean?  Specifically, how and where have you done this?

As far as I know you can't really use the Arduino IDE to write a bootloader.  I mean, you can use it to enter your source code, but you can't actually use it to program the bootloader onto your microcontroller.

If you're using a standard Arduino board, it comes pre-programmed with the Arduino bootloader.  The Arduino IDE can only program your microcontroller's flash memory by talking to this Arduino bootloader.  The Arduino bootloader doesn't support replacing itself with a different bootloader, but even if it did your Arduino IDE would no longer be able to program anything on that microcontroller.

I have not used the Arduino IDE to do anything with bootloaders.  My impression is that it does not give you enough control over memory mapping, linking, etc.  It also makes development "easier" by compiling in its own main() loop -- this is fine for normal applications but absolutely not what you want for a bootloader.

What you want to do is get something like Atmel Studio, and a JTAG programmer like the JTAGICE mk2 or similar.  Atmel Studio gives you control over every low-level aspect of your code, and the JTAG programmer will let you program the bootloader properly.

Explaning how to do flash programming from within your bootloader would be too much for this post.  But see the datasheet [here](http://www.atmel.com/search.aspx?q=avr109) and the application note AVR109 [here](http://www.atmel.com/search.aspx?q=avr109), they will give you some idea of what is involved.

Comment: Hi, I want to boot load through the UART1, but the default comes with the UART0. I found a default boot loader for atmega1284P here https://code.google.com/archive/p/optiboot/downloads . Can you please help me to modify the source so that it boot loads via UART1.